# Transforming rectangular (cartesian) to polar coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, math, colors, hue

Before asking the actual question, I want to mention that I know how to convert between the 2 coordinate systems. The thing that I need to understand is a picture in Wikipedia related to colors. This is the picture:

[image: pic]

Now, the formulas are as follows:

[image: Formulas]

So, using python, it's pretty easy to follow along and get this:

```
import numpy as np
R, G, B = 1/5, 3/5, 4/5

a = (2 * R - G - B) * 0.5
b = (np.sqrt(3) / 2) * (G - B)

H2 = np.arctan2(b, a)
C2 = np.sqrt(a*a + b*b)
```

The problem is that in this case H2 is **-2.808119481337961**, which is in radians. Even if I convert this to degrees using np.rad2deg(), I get **-160.8933946491309**.
I tried everything I could think of which includes using math instead of numpy (just in case), all sorts of other calculations, using external calculators as reference and I always get these results.

So, my question is how do they get H2=199.1° in the picture? What am I missing? All other calculations are fine (a, b, C2).

Comment: arctan2 gives angles in range `[-pi, pi]`, you need to return the angle to the range `[0, 2*pi]`, simply by adding `2*pi` if the angle is negative.

Comment: After converting to degrees, add 360 degrees to make the angle positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angles -160 and 199 are the same.

```
>>> math.degrees(H2)
-160.8933946491309
>>> math.degrees(H2) % 360
199.1066053508691
```

Comment: OMG, I can't believe I missed that... Thank you very much!